# Python: using .format method to populate string with list items

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

This seems like a question that should already have an answer, but I didn't find one.  If anyone knows of another question that has already answered this, please post a comment with the link.

My question is, is there a way to input the items from a list into a string using the .format method?  Using specific indices to format is kind of a pain, I am wondering if it is possible to use a "for i in list" technique.

So rather than this:

```
 x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print 'The first 4 items in my list are {}, {}, {}, {}'.format([x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3])
```

I could do something like:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print 'The first 4 items in my list are {}, {}, {}, {}'.format([i for i in x if i < 5])
```

if I try something along these lines, it won't work and I will get a "tuple index out of range" error, because it sees this as only 1 item rather than 4 separate items.  I'm just wondering if this is possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply unpack the list:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> 'The first 4 items in my list are {}, {}, {}, {}'.format(*x)
'The first 4 items in my list are 1, 2, 3, 4'
>>>
```

Any remaining arguments will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `string.join()` on your list comprehension

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print 'The first 4 items in my list are {}'.format(', '.join([str(i) for i in x if i < 4]))
# The first 4 items in my list are 1, 2, 3
```

Note: This only prints *three* elements, since only 3 elements in `x` match `< 4`

If your list comprehension was just an attempt to output only 4 elements, and you're not really interested in using list comprehensions otherwise, iCodez's solution is better and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
rev_arr = [4,3,2,1]
str_arr.format(', '.join([str(element) for element in rev_arr]))
```

I want that it should give an ouput like this 4 3 2 1 but its returning an empty string .
I am not able to understand why its returning an empty string.
I am newbie please elaborate the second line of the snippet to me